# Match a problem number to page number in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve a hackerrank problem. https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lisa-workbook/problem
Where I am given the list of problems in each chapter. And problems per page. As per Lisa the if the problem number matches the page number it is a special problem. Count the number of special problem in book

```
input : 3 [4, 2, 6, 1, 10]
output : 4
```

Explanation: 1st chapter has 4 problems that are split into 2 pages. 1st page has 3 problems. Problem 1 is special problem since it matches the page number i.e. 1

Chapter 3rd, 5th problem is special since it is on fifth page.

I created the implementation where I get the pages used by each chapter in form of tuples. I am stuck at how to match problem to page number??

```
import Data.List

solve::[Int] -> Int ->Int->Int-> [(Int, Int)]
solve [] _ _ _= []
solve (x:xss) g st ed = let (a, b) = (x `div` g, x `mod` g) in
    case b <= 0  of
        True -> (st, ((st + a) - 1)): solve xss g ((st  + a) +  1) 0
        False -> (st, st + a): solve xss g (st +  a + 1)  0
```

```
ghci> solve [4,2,6,1,10] 3 1 0 
[(1,2),(3,3),(4,5),(7,7),(8,11)]
```

[Problem explanation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-challenge-images/17892/1456473832-d122786d1e-bear_workbook.png)

corrected version:

```
solve::[Int] -> Int ->Int->Int-> [(Int, Int)]
solve [] _ _ _= []
solve (x:xss) g st ed = let (a, b) = (x `div` g, x `mod` g) in
    case b > 0  of 
        True ->  (st + 1, st + a + 1 ): solve xss g (st + a + 1) 0
        False -> (st + 1, st + a): solve xss g ( st + a) 0
```

```
*Main> solve [4, 2, 6, 1, 10] 3 0 0
[(1,2),(3,3),(4,5),(6,6),(7,10)]
```

Comment: I'm working on it at the moment and having quite a lot of fun at it, but meanwhile, I should point out that your function has an error in it. There is a one-page gap between chapters 3 and 4 (nothing on page 6).

Comment: I have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spoiler: the following is a complete solution.

First off, Haskell is a functional language, which means a lot of recursion. However, recursion is a common pattern, and one that is hard to read and reason about, and where mistakes are easy to make. This is why most recursion patterns are abstracted away in functions such as `foldr`, `scanr`, `length`, etc. In my opinion, functional programming is much easier to reason about when you think of the various data transformations as a sort of pipeline. This why there is no recursion in the following answer.

I'll take you through the process of building this pipeline. You'll see that working this way reduces the levels of indirection to a minimum, and in the end, the algorithm can pretty much be read like a paragraph of text.

---

First we start with a list representing the number of problems per chapiter, let's call it `dat`, since Haskell won't allow data:

```
let dat = [4, 2, 6, 1, 10]
```

Then we store the number of problems per page in variable k:

```
let k = 3
```

---

Let's start building our answer. We first want to zip the list of problem numbers with their corresponding chapter:

```
let step1 = zip [1..] dat
-- [(1,4),(2,2),(3,6),(4,1),(5,10)]
```

The next thing we need is to convert the number of problems into indexes and transforming the page number into the actual number of pages taken up by the chapter:

```
-- We turn 4 into [1,2,3,4]
let step2 = map ((,) . (ceiling . (/(fromIntegral k)) . fromIntegral . snd) 
            <*> (take . snd <*> zipWith const [1..] . repeat . fst)) step1
-- [(2,[1,2,3,4]),(1,[1,2]),(2,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),(1,[1]),(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])]
```

We need to sprinkle a few `fromIntegral`, since `/` is defined for `Fractional`, and we had two `Int`. The two `<*>` you see are from the Applicative instance of `->`. It's very useful if you want to inline everything. Basically, it feeds an argument to each of two functions, then applies the first to the second (`f <*> g = (\x -> f x (g x))`).

Next step is to use `scanl` to convert the page numbers into their cumulative values:

```
let step3 = scanl (\(a, as) (b, bs) -> (a + b, bs)) (1, []) step2
-- [(1,[]),(3,[1,2,3,4]),(4,[1,2]),(6,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),(7,[1]),(11,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])]
-- Notice that the elements of every tuple are offset by 1.
-- We'll fix this in the next step.
```

Let's fix this offset, still using the `<*>` trick to split our pipeline into two:

```
let step4 = zip . map fst <*> tail . map snd $ step3
-- [(1,[1,2,3,4]),(3,[1,2]),(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6]),(6,[1]),(7,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])]
```

Now, all we need is the first page of the chapter; we can deduce the last page from the number of questions. The function `chunksOf` from `Data.List.Split` is just what we need. It splits a list into groups of a certain length. Here, we will split the list of indexes into groups of `k` elements.

```
let step5 = map (\(a, bs) -> (a, zip [a..] $ chunksOf k bs)) $ step4
-- [(1,[(1,[1,2,3]),(2,[4])]),(3,[(3,[1,2])]),(4,[(4,[1,2,3]),(5,[4,5,6])]),(6,[(6,[1])]),(7,[(7,[1,2,3]),(8,[4,5,6]),(9,[7,8,9]),(10,[10])])]
```

Hey, we're almost done now! The output of step 5 is a bit messy, but we can already see the page numbers with their corresponding indexes. All we have left is to `filter` out every question number that is equal to its page number:

```
let step5point5 = map (filter (\(x, xs) -> x `elem` xs) . snd) step5
-- [[(1,[1,2,3])],[],[(5,[4,5,6])],[],[(9,[7,8,9]),(10,[10])]]
-- Oops, looks like we needed a concatMap
let step6 = concatMap (filter (\(x, xs) -> x `elem` xs) . snd) step5
-- [(1,[1,2,3]),(5,[4,5,6]),(9,[7,8,9]),(10,[10])]
-- Much better.
```

Now, all that's left is to count the number of elements:

```
let step7 = length step6
-- 4
```

The whole thing looks like this

```
solve k = step7 . step6 . step5 . step4 . step3 . step2 . step1
    where step1 = zip [1..]
          step2 = map ((,) . (ceiling . (/(fromIntegral k)) . fromIntegral . snd) 
                  <*> (take . snd <*> zipWith const [1..] . repeat . fst))
          step3 = scanl (\(a, as) (b, bs) -> (a + b, bs)) (1, [])
          step4 = zip . map fst <*> tail . map snd
          step5 = map (\(a, bs) -> (a, zip [a..] $ chunksOf 3 bs))
          step6 = concatMap (filter (\(x, xs) -> x `elem` xs  ) . snd)
          step7 = length
```

As a side note, if you like working of Hackerrank, you can always look at successful answers by going to Submissions->Leaderboard->View solution.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking the question, "what pages are used by each chapter?", you could ask the question "what range of problems is there on each page?" If you came up with a data structure to answer this question, it's easy to run queries against this data structure to count how many pages contain a problem with the same number.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
isInInclusiveRange :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
isInInclusiveRange x (lo, hi) = lo <= x && x <= hi

pages :: [Int]
pages = [1..]

specialProblemsCount :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
specialProblemsCount problemsPerPage problemsPerChapter =
  length  (filter (\(page, range) -> isInInclusiveRange page range) (zip pages rangesOfProblems))
  where
    rangesOfProblemsForChapterWithThisManyProblems :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
    rangesOfProblemsForChapterWithThisManyProblems problems = loop 1
      where
        {-- In this loop: lo is the lowest problem on the page (inclusive);
            hi is the highest problem on the page (inclusive). --}
        loop :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
        loop lo
          | lo > problems = []
          | otherwise =
            let hi = min problems (lo + problemsPerPage - 1) in
            (lo, hi) : loop (hi + 1)

    rangesOfProblems :: [(Int, Int)]
    rangesOfProblems =
      concatMap rangesOfProblemsForChapterWithThisManyProblems problemsPerChapter
```

Here, `rangesOfProblems` is the list data structure that answers the question "what range of problems is there on each page?" For your example, it would look like: `[(1, 3), (4, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 6), (1, 3), (4, 6), (7, 9), (9, 10)]`. That is, the first page has the problem range `(1, 3)` (inclusive on both ends); the second page has the problem range `(4, 4)`; etc. The trick is that `rangesOfProblemsForChapterThisManyProblems`, when given as argument the number of problems in a chapter, returns a list describing the problem ranges for each page of the chapter. `concatMap` takes the lists for each chapter and combines them into a single list, just as the bookbinder concatenates the chapters into a single book. :)

If there's a function or pattern you don't recognize in this post, don't hesitate to add a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate